# Old csh alias into bash

Tags: linux, bash, csh

I'm currently updating some of our scripts from the unreadable world of csh to bash. We have a local alias stored on our system which is used throughout

```
alias sc 'set \!:2 = `current -\!:1 | cut -c7-`'
```

This uses a C executable called current which we use to identify the current selected data type. There are 5 data types here image(i), region(r), curve(c), textfile(t) or listfile (l)

The usage of this alias is fairly straightforward
`sc i A_image`

This will find the currently selected image and set the value (which will be an integer) and set the retrieved value to the parameter $A_image which can then be used later in the script.

Similarly `sc r Aregion` will find the currently selected region and set it to the parameter $Aregion.

I have never really seen the used of !:2 in csh and do not know what it is called. Is there a way I can implement this functionality in bash as it is very useful for our scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those appear to be history-like word/argument selectors.

So `!:2` is the second argument to the alias and `!:1` is the first argument to the alias.

So `sc i A_image` ends up calling

```
set A_image = `current -i | cut -c7-`
```

bash aliases can't take arguments, you need to use functions for that (functions are generally more useful anyway).

The equivalent bash 4.2+ function would be

```
sc() {
    declare -g "$2=$(current "$1" | cut -c7-)"
}
```

For bash 3.1+ it would be

```
sc() {
    printf -v "$2" -- %s "$(current "$1" | cut -c7-)"
}
```

For older bash or `/bin/sh` it would be

```
sc() {
    eval "$2=\$(current \"$1\" | cut -c7-)`"
}
```

but this version is unsafe in general for untrusted input.

(All functions above untested but should work just fine.)